# Smarty error: Call to a member function get_articlelist_primary() on a non-object

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I am forced to use Smarty for a project but the server is running slow, so I tried to work with it locally on MAMP.

I am a complete beginner when it comes to Smarty.

First I downloaded smarty then in index.php for the site I am making, I made a class:

```
class Panel{
    public function __construct__(){}
    public function get_articlelist_primary(){return array();}
}
```

Then I made an instance:

```
$panelObj=new Panel();
```

Did my thing with Smarty:

```
require_once("../Smarty-3.1.20/libs/Smarty.class.php");
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = 'views';
$smarty->compile_dir = 'tmp';
$smarty->assign("panelObj",$panelObj);
$smarty->display("index.tpl");
```

Then I made a template, and it dosen't work. The PHP error log says:

```
[17-Oct-2014 20:48:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_articlelist_primary() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/LanderTemplate/tmp/3dd4ab168909a8c2acf37974fa4b15c661cc2857.file.index.tpl.php on line 377
```

Line 377 in the compiled template is:

```
if (count($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['panelObj']->value->get_articlelist_primary())) {?></div><?php }?>
```

Wrote this line in the compiled template to error log it:

```
<?php error_log(print_r($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['panelObj'],1));
```

It returned:

```
[17-Oct-2014 20:48:38 Europe/Berlin] Smarty_Variable Object
(
    [value] => 
    [nocache] => 
    [scope] => 0
    [_loop] => 
)
```

It seems that "value" should be equal to the instance since I had assigned it, but it is just blank. What could be the reason for this? I'm using Smarty 3.1.20.

Comment: You have given lots of details, but appear to be missing the (uncompiled) Smarty template.

Comment: @IMSop it's not really relevant because you know based on what is compiled that I did in fact reference `$panelObj->get_articlelist_primary()`, but when I have a chance I can update it. The issue us, why is `[value]` empty?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are doing everything fine so please try this code to make sure you have `$panelObj` defined in current scope.

```
class Panel{
    public function __construct(){}
    public function get_articlelist_primary(){return array();}
}
$panelObj=new Panel();

var_dump($panelObj);
$smarty->assign("panelObj",$panelObj);
$smarty->display("index.tpl");
```

And in `index.tpl` file:

```
{$panelObj->get_articlelist_primary()}
```

If you have error_reporting enabled, you will see only notice:

```
object(Panel)#17 (0) { }
Notice: Array to string conversion in ...\templates_c\6a7a7402e26bab6fe66fe3d214cc5fb929376cc9.file.sb.tpl.php on line 34
Array
```

because you return array in this function, but as you see this class method can be launched without any problem. I've tested it in `3.1.19` version

Comment: The var_dump outputs `object(Panel)#3 (0) { }`, but strangely, when I call `$this->hi="hello";` in the `__construct__` method, it still returns an empty Panel. But if I set the variable outside of the class, it works. Does this give a clue?

Comment: And PS yes I got the array to string conversion error.

Comment: @NickManning Ok, so it seems it does work for you. You should have constructor with name `__construct` and not `__construct__` And I think you cannot debug it this way. So methods works for you, and if you change the name of constructor as I said, you can then in Smarty template file use `{$panelObj->hi}` and it will display you `hello`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I'm able to debug easier...still have the error on line 377 like in the original question though.

Comment: @NickManning Have you used exact code I showed? There is no error but only notice about array to string conversion. Everything else is working fine here